How can I register an S-Corp if I live in a rental property and do not have a business office?
I live in California and have recently obtained my loan officer and insurance agent licenses. I am planning to register an S-Corp and launch a website to sell loan and insurance products. I do not intend to open a physical office anytime soon.
The issue I am facing is that I currently live in a rental property and would prefer not to use this address as my business address. I am unsure if I am even allowed to do that, as it seems the lease agreement might need to specify that I intend to use the rental address for business purposes.
From my research, it appears that postal services like UPS offer mailboxes that provide a real address, which can be used for registering a company. There are also services that offer registered agent services in addition to a mailbox or real address (Although I am unsure if I need a registered agent service because I don't know what exactly they're gonna do for me).
Please help me understand the difference between renting a physical office versus a virtual office to start my online business? Do you think I will face a problem if I don't have a real office?

Cross post from Law@SE: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/104635/how-can-i-register-an-s-corp-if-i-live-in-a-rental-property-and-do-not-have-a-bu

I'm not sure this question is answerable in its current format.  You seem to be asking for product and service recommendations which will be closed because they tend to go out of date rather quickly.  If you wanted to ask a question like "What is the advantage of a registered agent over just renting a PO box?" that should be on topic.  You could probably pull another question or two out of this and ask them as separate on-topic questions.

@JustinCave: Thanks for your comment. I will try to edit my question.

Either get an office or use your home address. Or ask the state if they will accept an accommodation address like a rented mailbox, but I think they will want a real location .

Also, there are very basic instructions both on the SoS and the FTB websites, and tons of resources on Google, all of which you seem to have skipped.

You are required to have a Registered Agent. This is an office which is open normal business hours as defined by the courts.  It exists for the purpose of serving legal notice, i.e. the guy who throws papers at you and says "You've been SERVED!"  It has to be open.  What you can't do is have a situation where the process server is trying to serve you and can't find anyone to serve after several tries. Then, your counterparty comes to court with proof of that, says "let's proceed without them", and you get wrecked in court unless their case is terrible.
A proper Registered Agent recognizes what service looks like, and will make efforts to notify you of the service.  In an ideal circumtstance, you never hear from them.
A PMB (Private Mail Box) such as The UPS Store is not the same as a Registered Agent. They have fulfilled their duty to you if. they simply throw your legal notice in your mailbox and not lift a finger to notify you, and again you get wrecked in court.
State laws vary as to whether your organization needs to provide a genuine residential address. I often research California corporations/LLCs to validate Amazon sellers, and all the ones (who actually bothered to register in CA) often have a workshop/warehouse but always have a street address. The latter usually goes to a residence, typically an apartment building.
So I suspect California is not allowing PMBs.
You may be able to use the office of your attorney.  However this may be limited by the standards of your profession. Sometimes these matters are decided by a nonprofit/NGO such as a bar or board who certifies practitioners.
Another option is to register in a more friendly state, e.g. Wyoming is a popular incorporation state. However if you're doing business in a different state, you'll need to register "as a foreign corporation/LLC" in that state, and must have a Registered Agent in that state, and may still face their rules regarding a physical address.  PMBs have fallen very much out of favor in recent years.
